# MySQL query - why doesn't it use the index in this case?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

MySQL query (ver 5.1.61)

```
SELECT alerts.*,
       devices.user_id
  FROM alerts
       left JOIN devices
          ON alerts.device_id = devices.id
 WHERE    devices.name = 'myval'
```

There is an index on "alerts.device_id"
MySQL in Explain does not use the index, it shows type "ALL" and rows being the full count of rows in the table.

I can't understand why it doesn't use this index.
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the output of EXPLAIN.

Comment: Sorry I over simplified the actual query and missed out the problem bits!  Will update this when I find it again.

Answer (score 1):

The index are not getting picked, because you have not used it, neither in the select nor in the where clause.

You need to add an index on `device.name`

You can do one thing to force the engine to consider the index if it is a primary key and its value if is more than 0, like :

```
SELECT alerts.*,
       devices.user_id
  FROM alerts
       left JOIN devices
          ON alerts.device_id = devices.id
 WHERE    devices.name = 'myval' and alerts.deviceid>0
```